# Non destructive way of deleting a key from a hash

Tags: ruby, hash, side-effects

Is there a non-destructive way of deleting a key value pair from a hash?

For example, if you did

```
original_hash = {:foo => :bar}
new_hash = original_hash
new_hash = new_hash.reject{|key, _| key == :foo}
```

or

```
original_hash = {:foo => :bar}
new_hash = original_hash
new_hash = new_hash.dup
new_hash.delete(:foo)
```

then `original_hash` is unchanged, and `new_hash` is changed, but they're a tad verbose. However, if you did

```
original_hash = {:foo => :bar}
new_hash = original_hash
new_hash.delete(:foo)
```

then `original_hash` is changed, which isn't what I want.

Is there a single method that does what I want?

Comment: `original_hash` *is* changed in your first example using `delete_if`. Also, `new_hash` in your second example using `delete` gets the value associated with `:foo`, i.e. `:bar`, not the hash itself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ActiveSupport provides a hash extension: [Hash#except](http://rubydoc.info/docs/rails/2.3.8/ActiveSupport/CoreExtensions/Hash/Except). It allows you to return a new hash except specified keys without modifying the original.

Assuming you have installed the active_support gem:

```
ruby-1.9.3> require 'active_support/core_ext/hash/except.rb'
 => true
 ruby-1.9.3> a = {x: 2, y: 1, z: 3}
 => {:x=>2, :y=>1, :z=>3} 
ruby-1.9.3> b = a.except(:x)
 => {:y=>1, :z=>3} 
ruby-1.9.3> c = a.except(:x, :y)
 => {:z=>3} 
ruby-1.9.3> a
 => {:x=>2, :y=>1, :z=>3} 
ruby-1.9.3> b
 => {:y=>1, :z=>3} 
ruby-1.9.3> c
 => {:z=>3}
```

Comment: I don't use ActiveSupport, but the fact that they supply such a method is good evidence that Ruby itself doesn't have such a method.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, you want `reject`:

```
new_hash = original_hash.reject{|key, _| key == :foo}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that new_hash is a reference unless you explicitly tell Ruby to duplicate the object.  You're on the right track using dup, the only thing I might recommend is to do

```
new_hash = original_hash.dup
```

because I think thats more explicit about what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

What about chaining the dup to make it less verbose?

```
new_hash = original_hash.dup.delete_if{|key, _| key == :foo}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
original_hash.clone.tap {|h| h.delete key}
```

`tap` is arguably less clunky than declaring a new variable, mostly because it's on the same line.

`clone` is, I think, more explicitly a flat copy than `dup`, though of course for hashes it makes little difference.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.